# Arithmetic on uint8, int8

Tags: go, int

What is the reason for getting negative and zero results in the Arithmetic operation on **unit8** and **int8** data types for the given example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

     var u uint8 = 255
     fmt.Println(u, u+1, u*u) // "255 0 1"
     var i int8 = 127
     fmt.Println(i, i+1, i*i) // "127 -128 1"
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_a2KHP29t5p

Comment: You could include in question, what result would you expect then?

Comment: @hyde I'm learning Golang in my understanding those resulted in an overflow of the data type values is what I know.

Comment: Generally, 127 = 01111111b; that+1 = 10000000b = -128 when interpreted as signed two's complement integer. But type conversion rules of language are important too, so not writing an answer for Go.

Comment: And 255 = 11111111b; that+1 = 100000000b with 9 bits, unsigned 8 bit integer only fits 00000000b = 0, which is how basically all modern CPUs and languages handle unsigned overflow.

Comment: @hyde Thanks now understood how addition works.

Comment: I converted those two comments into an answer, if that's exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the other answer, and unlike some other programming languages, Go handles all integer overflow in a well-defined manner similar to what happens on most current CPUs at assembly level.

---

127 = 0111 1111 binary

that + 1 = 1000 0000 binary

that interpreted as signed two's complement 8 bit integer is -128.

---

255 = 1111 1111 binary

that + 1 = 1 0000 0000 binary (note 9 bits)

That would be 256 if we had 9 bits, but we don't, we have only 8 so it becomes 0000 0000 binary, which is 0.

---

Similarly for multiplication:

127*127 = 16129 = ‭0011 1111 0000 0001‬ bin

255 * 255 = 65025 = ‭1111 1110 0000 0001‬ bin

Both have lower 8 bits as 0000 0001 bin = 1

---

Note: most of the time, if you are relying on integer overflow, you should take a step back and think hard if this is the best way to do what you are doing. This is very low level behavior, involving exact bitwise behavior, and should always be accompanied with enough comments explaining what and why.

Comment: What about the multiplication?

Comment: From the other answer's quote: *"For unsigned integer values, the operations +, -, *, and << are computed modulo 2n, where n is the bit width of the unsigned integer's type."* which basically means, just remove the bits which won't fit in the type.

Comment: Updated with multiplication

Answer (score 4):

Go does not panic for integer overflow in runtime. As per [doc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_overflow):

> For unsigned integer values, the operations +, -, *, and << are
>   computed modulo 2n, where n is the bit width of the unsigned integer's
>   type. Loosely speaking, these unsigned integer operations discard high
>   bits upon overflow, and programs may rely on "wrap around".
>
> For signed integers, the operations +, -, *, /, and << may legally
>   overflow and the resulting value exists and is deterministically
>   defined by the signed integer representation, the operation, and its
>   operands. No exception is raised as a result of overflow. A compiler
>   may not optimize code under the assumption that overflow does not
>   occur. For instance, it may not assume that x < x + 1 is always true.

Comment: Ha, I can't help but feel that text is a subtle dig at how C and C++ handle the issue!

Comment: I thought the same. Go itself is sort of a subtle dig at C 